# Gridview row not getting updated properly in nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` for which I want to update one column always. So what I did is, on `UpdateCommand` I have written the code below :-

```
protected void GrdCategoryDetails_UpdateCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    string Amount = string.Empty;
    Amount = e.Record["AMOUNT"].ToString();
    Session["V_ID"] = e.Record["VENDOR_ID"];
    Session["Amount"] = Amount;
}

public void RowDataBound(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == GridRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string Vendor_ID = Convert.ToString(Session["V_ID"]);
        if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == Vendor_ID)
        {
            string Amount = Convert.ToString(Session["Amount"]);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

So what it does is, It UPDATES my row with the updated value.

Now what happening here is,

> When I go to update the second row of the column in the gridview, the earlier value in the first row gets disappeared and the second value gets updated. WHY this is happening ??
>
> NOTE The gridview which I am updating is the NESTED gridview

```
<cc1:Grid ID="GrdVendor" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
    AllowSorting="false" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="0" AllowAddingRecords="false"
    AllowPageSizeSelection="false">
    <Columns>
        <cc1:Column ID="c_category" DataField="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE" HeaderText="Vendor Category"
            runat="server" Visible="true" Align="left" HeaderAlign="left" Width="30%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="c_outStanding_Req_Amt" DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Required Amount"
            runat="server" Visible="true" Align="right" HeaderAlign="right" Width="30%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="c_OutStanding_Amt" DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Amount"
            runat="server" Visible="true" Align="right" HeaderAlign="right" Width="30%">
        </cc1:Column>
    </Columns>
    <MasterDetailSettings LoadingMode="OnCallback" />
    <DetailGrids>
        <cc1:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdCategoryDetails" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE"
             AllowSorting="false" DataSourceID="vendor_Details" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" OnUpdateCommand="GrdCategoryDetails_UpdateCommand"
            PageSize="0" AllowPaging="false" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowPageSizeSelection="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" State="Collapsed" ShowFooter="false" Width="98%"
            Style="overflow: scroll">
            <Columns>
                <cc1:Column AllowEdit="true" HeaderText="Edit">
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="CVendor_ID" DataField="VENDOR_ID" HeaderText="Vendor ID" runat="server"
                    Visible="true" Align="left" HeaderAlign="left">
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="cVendor_Name" DataField="VENDOR_NAME" HeaderText="Vendor Name" runat="server"
                    Width="20%%" Visible="true" Align="left" HeaderAlign="left">
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="cVendor_OutStanding_Req_Amt" DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Required Amount"
                    Width="20%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="right" HeaderAlign="right">
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="Vendor_outStandingAmount" DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Amount"
                    Width="20%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="right" HeaderAlign="right">
                </cc1:Column>
                <cc1:Column ID="AMOUNT" DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="Amount" Width="25%" runat="server"
                    Visible="true" Align="right" HeaderAlign="right">
                    <TemplateSettings TemplateId="tempAmount" />
                </cc1:Column>
            </Columns>
            <Templates>
                <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tempAmount" ControlID="txtAddAmount">
                    <Template>
                    </Template>
                </cc1:GridTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <MasterDetailSettings LoadingMode="OnCallback" />
            <DetailGrids>
                <cc1:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="grid3" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    AllowSorting="false" PageSize="0" AllowPaging="false" AllowAddingRecords="false"
                    AllowPageSizeSelection="false" ShowFooter="false" DataSourceID="Vendor_Details1"
                   Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <cc1:Column ID="C_Organization_Name" DataField="ORGANIZATION_NAME" HeaderText="Organization Name"
                            Width="15%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="C_T_vendorName" DataField="VENDOR_NAME" HeaderText="Vendor Name"
                            Width="20%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="c_vendor_lookup_type_code" DataField="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE" HeaderText="Vendor Type"
                            Width="20%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="C_Invoice_Number" DataField="INVOICE_NUM" HeaderText="Invoice Number"
                            Width="15%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="middle" HeaderAlign="middle">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="c_OutS_Req_Amt" DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Required Amount"
                            Width="15%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="c_OutStand_Amount" DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" HeaderText="OutStanding Amount"
                            Width="15%" runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="InvoiceAmount" DataField="InvoiceAmount" HeaderText="Amount" Width="20%"
                            runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="CVendor_id1" DataField="VENDOR_ID" HeaderText="Vendor_ID" Width="20%"
                            runat="server" Visible="true" Align="center" HeaderAlign="center">
                        </cc1:Column>
                    </Columns>
                    <Templates>
                        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="InvoiceDetailsAmount" ControlID="txtInvoiceAmount">
                            <Template>
                                <input type="text" id="InvoiceAmount" /></Template>
                        </cc1:GridTemplate>
                    </Templates>
                </cc1:DetailGrid>
            </DetailGrids>
        </cc1:DetailGrid>
    </DetailGrids>
</cc1:Grid>
```

> I am updating the GrdCategoryDetails Gridview.